# Could the refractive index of a material change?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction

Is it possible that the refractive index of a material could change? If so, what are those factors and what kind of variation could they bring?

Comment: Change in time or over a distance?

Answer (score 2):

The refractive index of a dielectric material with nonlinear behavior can also be changed by an application of an external DC electric field. This is an example of the [electro-optic effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro%E2%80%93optic_effect). When the dependence is quadratic on the magnitude of the electric field, it is called the [DC Kerr effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) and it has applications in nonlinear optics. For example you can use it in [optical phase modulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-optic_modulator).

Comment: An applied DC-field would produce the Pockels effect, and an applied electromagnetic field (cw-laser or pulsed laser) produces the electro-optic effect, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: From what I've read, the difference between the Pockels effect and the Kerr effect is more about the fact that the former depends linearly on the applied field, while the latter depends quadratically on it. I'm realizing "electro-optic effect" might be too vague a term, since there are many effects that fall under that umbrella.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The refractive index of water changes with temperature. It falls slightly as the temperature rises.

[Water refractive index in dependence on temperature and
wavelength: a simple approximation
Alexey N. Bashkatov , Elina A. Genina](http://optics.sgu.ru/_media/optics/staff/bashkatov/bashkatov_spie_03_5068_393.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

One can alter the refractive index of a medium such as biological tissue using Ultrasound. This is used in certain types of medical imaging.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share an interesting example with you that you see in your daily life but still don't notice. Our own atmosphere is composed  of various layers of varying densities ( both physical and optical ) hence due to a light ray follows a unique path in accordance the variation of the refractive index with the height hence we can't see beyond a particular distance on the road. Next we can discuss the fact that not even all components of the white light have similar refractive index for the same material due to difference in wavelegths of the different components. Also one can do some research upon the physical factors that determine the cauchy's coefficient .

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning about this myself.  The index of refraction really has meaning when you are talking about two indexes of refraction in relation with each other.  For example, the vacuum of space has No effect on bending or refracting light (excluding the idea of gravity from black holes and other such objects affecting the path of light). A perfect vacuum has been given the arbitrary value of 1, as a constant and comparative value.  Air, by comparison to this starting point, has an index of refraction of 1.0003.  This value is so small, that most professors will suggest that their students simply think of it as the same as a vacuum, for purposes of doing calculations.  Water has an approximate index of refraction of 1.33, and glass an approximate value of 1.51. You divide the index of refraction of the first material (called "n1") by the value of the index of refraction of the second material (called "n2), and this value will allow you to calculate how strongly light will bend as the light (called the incident light) from the first medium strikes the second medium (called the refracted light).  The higher the index of refraction, the more dense the medium is that it travels through.  Further, the more slowly light will travel through the medium.  The wavelength of light is also a factor in light propagation through a medium, which is why we have light diffracting and separating into different colors through a prism, or through a raindrop, creating the rainbows we see.

Glycerin, a thick, viscous fluid, has an approximate index of refraction of 1.47.  Acrylic, a solid plastic, has a very close value to glycerin, of 1.49.
However, if you were to place a piece of acrylic into a container of glycerin, you will still see the acrylic in the fluid.  The tiny 0.02 difference between the two is enough that you will still be able to make out the acrylic sitting inside the glycerin.  If the two materials matched exactly, then the acrylic would be invisible to the viewer, just as those water-absorbant polymers are that sit in a container of water, as their indices of refraction match exactly.

Which leads us to your question:  how can an index of refraction be altered?

In the example of glycerin, the amount of sugar dissolved in the glycerin will change the index of refraction.  Adding water to the glycerin to dilute it will lower the index of refraction of glycerin, as water has an index of refraction of 1.33, and glycerin 1.47.  There is an entire optical industry devoted to the creation of precision fluids such as this, where a glass lens may be immersed in a fluid that matches its index of refraction precisely, in order to better view a specimen that has been sandwiched between two glass slides (that have an index of refraction of 1.51).  Cargille is such a company that produces immersion fluids such as this.  Their fluids are extremely expensive; a quarter ounce can cost 33 dollars or more, and 16 fluid ounces can cost almost 300 dollars.  You can go to their website and they will describe in detail their various optical fluids, but I don't believe they explain how they precisely engineer their index of refraction.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the refractive index of a material is performed in optical materials through either the [Kerr effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) or the [Pockels effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pockels_effect), to name a few. Laser pulses have, when pulsed properly through modelocking or Q-switching, potentially extremely high peak powers, which can induce refractive index changes in a material such as for example KTP-crystals. This manifests itself for example through something called self-focusing, where the intensity profile of a laser beam varies spatially, leading to the refractive index change in the crystal which induces self focusing.

[Kerr-lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr-lens_modelocking) works in a fashion like this.